# How do I uninstall eXist-db?

Tags: command-line, java, uninstall

We had an older server with Ubuntu 14.04 and eXist-db 2.2 that is used purely for testing. I need to uninstall eXist-db from it using command line, but I seem to fail. I tried using `uninstall.jar` of eXist-db like this:

```
sudo java -jar uninstall.jar
```

but I only get

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile uninstall.jar
```

I guess I could do `rm -rf` but I don't think it would be smart, as I guess eXist uses other folders beside the one that is its installation path: `/usr/share/exist-db/`.

I need to do this in order to install latest version of the base.

What is the correct way to uninstall eXist-db using command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as I guess eXist uses other folders beside the one that is its installation path: /usr/share/exist-db/.

A jar file should contain its installation to the installation path. Proof is in the method of installation: it should be done =without= the need for `sudo`. Any alterations that need to be done outside of it should be manual. So deleting it using `rm` is a valid/correct method.

From the [installer](https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/tree/develop/installer):

> - Create a directory in $EXIST_HOME and copy the .xar files of all application
>     packages you want to have installed there.

That would suggest it is only installed in $HOME.

Another method would be to redownload the software, and use the new downloaded uninstaller (as your current one seems corrupted)